# Implementing the Dutch IJ digraph as a ligature

Tags: typography, font-design, glyphs, opentype

I'm designing a display typeface and having some trouble deciding how to implement the uppercase Dutch digraph "IJ". I have designed a ligature that combines the "I" and "J" to form what looks like a broken "U".

Here is a comparison of my "IJ" ligature against the distinct "I" and "J" glyphs:

[image]

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_(digraph)#Not_a_digraph), an "I" followed by a "J" doesn't always form a digraph; would the ligature still be acceptable in those cases, or would that be considered incorrect?

I'm going to include the ligature in the font, there is no question there, my only problem is how to implement it and make it available to users through OpenType features and the use of the [IJ Unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0132/index.htm). How should I consider the language/locale of the user? Should the ligature be the default;

- e.g. used for the "IJ" character and as a standard ligature (OpenType feature `liga`) for "I"+"J"?

Or an optional stylistic alternative;

- e.g. stylistic alternate (OpenType feature `salt`) for the "IJ" character and a discretionary ligature (OpenType feature `dlig`) for "I"+"J"?

---

Note, I'm asking about the technical implementation (through OpenType features) here; For critique of the ligature design itself see [Is this Dutch IJ ligature suitable and readable to native speakers?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/82368/52050).

Comment: I don't know dutch so can't help you with that. Only suggestion would be to maybe try making the I taller and the hook of the J shorter to balance them out a bit more. Right now the J is dominant.

Comment: I did that to a degree as you can see, everything in the typeface aligns to a few grid lines so it was a choice between what it is now or (almost) no hook. I felt that was the best option but it's certainly something to think about again, thanks!

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I've made some edits to focus more on the implementation, I'll take your suggestion and ask another question to critique the suitability of the ligature itself

Comment: I see that you indeed did what @DA01 suggested but i would take it one step further and make it even more pronounced. maybe push it fluch with teh nding hook?

Comment: @joojaa your comment would be more appropriate [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/82368/52050) :)

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that your *Ĳ* glyph is appropriate to the Dutch eye (which I cannot tell), it should be used as a ligature for *I+J* by default for Dutch texts.

While you can restrict every OpenType feature to specific locales, the arguably best way to do this would be via the feature `locl`, which is specifically reserved for such purposes. The OpenType cookbook [uses this very case as an example](http://opentypecookbook.com/common-techniques/):

```
feature locl {

    script latn;

        language NLD exclude_dflt;
            lookup DutchIJ {
                sub I J by IJ.dutch;
            } DutchIJ;

} locl;
```

If the user properly sets the locale of the text, this should ensure that the ligature is used in Dutch text, but not for any other language. (Sidenote: It should not be activated for Afrikaans, as the absence of *Ĳ* is one of the distinguishing features of Afrikaans orthography.)

I do not see any reason to not use your ligature for the Ĳ Unicode character (U+0132), as there is no legitimate use of this character outside the Dutch language and in Dutch it should not be used for the exceptions.

> According to Wikipedia, an "I" followed by a "J" doesn't always form a digraph; would the ligature still be acceptable in those cases, or would that be considered incorrect?

It would be considered incorrect, but such cases are the exception. Also such exception exist for almost every ligature. E.g., in German, you would not have the typical ligatures involving the letter *f* in the composite words such as *Auffahrt* or *Kaufleute.*

There are two ways to deal with this:

- The user has to use a [zero-width non-joiner (ZWNJ)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) to suppress the ligature in cases, where it’s not intended, i.e., write `FI|JI` instead of `FIJI` (with `|` indicating the ZWNJ). If you expect your fonts to be used by non-professionals, you should arguably instruct them on this.
- The exceptions are hard-coded into the font. Given that exceptions are rare in this case, this is rather feasible. [In this article](http://www.underware.nl/blog/2014/10/typesetting-the-dutch-ij/) (which is a great source on the *Ĳ* in general, by the way), the Dutch type foundry Underware states that this is what they are doing. While such a hard-coding may capture the vast majority of exceptions, it cannot be perfect, e.g., it cannot possibly cover all proper names in the world.

  Also, this is arguably nothing that should be handled by font features, but by dictionaries and the end user.

Comment: Surely Underware's "In Dutch the ij is a digraph, or – if you prefer – a *ligature*..." is wrong? A ligature is a pure presentational form. No room for preferences; in orthographic terms it's a digraph ("a pair of characters used in the orthography of a language to write [..] a single phoneme (distinct sound)" ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography))). As a character, it is more than just another ligature, and it's just like the `æ` is "originally a ligature representing a Latin diphthong" ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Æ)), a full Character of its own.

Comment: @RadLexus: Well, there are inevitable grey zones and overlaps between *character, ligature,* and *digraph.* E.g., nothing switches from being treated as two separate characters to being treated as a single character over night – such a process usually takes several centuries. The *ĳ* is somewhere in between. It sometimes has a specific shape (ligature), but often doesn’t; it is treated as a single character in many respects but as two separate characters in others. Anyway, what does this have to do with the answer?

Comment: Ah, it was just a tangent on your excellent answer! The article is very good and covers the potential problems well.

Comment: `sub IJ by IJ.dutch` by itself doesn't make sense because `IJ` is not used in actual Dutch texts, `I` followed by `J` is typed – I assume this is in addition to a ligature substitution?

Comment: @AdamJagosz: Yeah, that’s weird. Of course you could theoretically have one *IJ* ligature for normal use and one special *Ĳ* ligature for Dutch, but I rather guess that there’s a space missing here. See my edit.

Comment: That's still not a proper implementation as `locl` is not controlled by the user. The way to go is using `dlig` so that the user enables the ligature at their discretion and can disable it for exceptions like Fiji, bijou or bijectie.

Comment: @AdamJagosz: Is there any official guidance on this? Last time I checked (which is admittedly years ago), the documentation was all rather muddy and contained at least some bad examples (like s→ſ as a general historical substitution). Practically speaking, I would expect that any user who is knowledgeable and willing to disable ligatures for individual words is more than willing to use a ZWNJ, which should be more robust, portable, etc. anyway.

Comment: I don't have a reference but `dlig` is what I always hear at typedrawers.com – maybe it'd be best to ask there. But yeah, ZWNJ saves the day.

Comment: The Cookbook uses `sub IJ by IJ.dutch;` not `sub I J by IJ.dutch;`.  Notice the lack of space.  In the Cookbook font example it appears to only work with the unicode character `Ĳ` (U+0132).  As has been commented the space will allow for a ligature of `I` followed by `J`.  I believe these are two different things even if they give the same end result.

Comment: @coderfin: Interesting, I apparently didn’t notice this and autocorrected it. Since the only reason to use the Ĳ character (U+0132) is for Dutch texts or names, I fail to see the point of having a Dutch and non-Dutch variant of this character. Therefore I would think the variant given in my answer makes more sense.